# Gitlab CI with PHP

Tags: php, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm currently having trouble with my gitlab-ci.yml pipeline where I'm trying to set up a test and deployment stage for one of my php file. I'm also not too sure how does docker work in gitlab as well. This is my first time using gitlab ci with php so I apologize if my codes are abit messy and redundant.

My PHP file:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
include "config.php"; // Using database connection file here

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true || $_SESSION["roles"] !== 'Reporter')
{
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
        
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{       
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $username = $_SESSION["username"];

    $insert = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `bugreport`(`title`, `keyword`, `description`, `status`, `username`) VALUES ('$title', '$keyword','$description', 'Open', '$username')");
    echo "Bug report raised!<br />";
    
    if(!$insert)
    {
        echo mysqli_error();
    }
}

mysqli_close($link); // Close connection
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Raise Bug Report</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Raise bug report</h1>
    </div>
    <p>
    <form method="POST">
  Title : <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" size="50" Required>
  <br/>
  Keyword : <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Keyword" size="50" Required>
  <br/>
  Description : <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description" size="50" Required>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
   <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">  
  <a href="welcome.php" class="btn btn-danger">Back to Home</a>
</form>

    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
# Select image from https://hub.docker.com/_/php/
image: php:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get update -yqq
  - apt-get install -yqq git libmcrypt-dev libpq-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libvpx-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev libbz2-dev libgmp3-dev libldap2-dev unixodbc-dev libsqlite3-dev libaspell-dev libsnmp-dev libpcre3-dev libtidy-dev
  - apt-get install git -yqq
  - curl --location --output /usr/local/bin/phpunit https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
  - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpunit
  - docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

stages:
  - test
  - deployment

test: 
  stage: test
  script: phpunit --configuration phpunit_myapp.xml
  artifacts: 
        paths: 
          - Report.*

deployment:
   stage:
```

Comment: What issue you are facing? Could you please provide the errors or issue details in your questions. It is unclear from your question, what is the problem.

Comment: @SouravAtta Sorry sorry, im quite a dummy to programming especially to gitlab.

Comment: @SouravAtta bascially whenever i update or add a new feature, i will commit the changes and use GitLab to track it as a CI/CD with the title, keyword, username and description